# Using ListFragment in a custom Dialog have issue and show Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, xml

I  `ListFragment` with multiple maps,with a custom `DialogFragment`. Its showing some error.
I am stuck there help me out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/sky_blue"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/upcomingShifts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_24sp"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_10dp"
        android:text="@string/upcoming_shifts"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/lvMapFragment"
            class="android.support.v4.app.ListFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my custom dialog code

```
@Override

    protected Dialog onCreateDialogPost(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.AppDialogTheme);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_up_coming_shift);
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
//        dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.AppDialogPullAnimation;
        WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
        Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point point = new Point();
        display.getSize(point);
        int width = point.x - 40;
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        init();
        return dialog;
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code where you inflate the layout and also the error log.

Comment: please post error too.

Comment: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class fragment

Answer (score -1):

You can try to change the layout.

Your code:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/lvMapFragment"
        class="android.support.v4.app.ListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

New code:

```
<fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:name="package_name_of_your_class_that_extends_ListFragment"
            android:id="@+id/lvMapFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/name_of_your_layout_use_in_above_class"
            />
```

Comment: its not working in my case because i not extends listfragment